# Problems posting data into json url

Tags: php, json, post, youtube-api

Hey I'm sure this is an easy fix but it's driving me nuts.

I'm working with the youtube api and I'm trying to post a user generated search term into the url like so:

```
<form action="pagination.php" method="post">
<input style="width:50%" type="text" name="search_term">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?

$search_term = $_POST['search_term'];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds  
/api/videos?q='.$search_term.'&safeSearch=none&orderby=viewCount&v=2&alt=json&start- 
index=75&max-results=50');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 

$data = json_decode($output,true);

$info = $data["feed"];
$video = $info["entry"];
$nVideo = count($video);



echo "<ul style='float:right'>";
foreach($video as $video) {
echo '<img src="'.$video['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url'].'"><br><br>';
$title = $video['title']['$t'];
$video_id = $video['media$group']['yt$videoid']['$t'];
echo '<a href="search_4.php?video_get_id='.$video_id.'">'.$title.'</a>';
echo '<br>';
```

When I run this code nothing happens, however if I manually assign a value to $search_term like this:

```
$search_term = 'baseball';
```

everything works perfectly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: $search_term doesn't seem to be used anywhere

Comment: Its in the url : http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds  
/api/videos?q='.$search_term.'&safeSearch=none&orderby=viewCount&v=2&alt=json&start- 
index=75&max-results=50'

Comment: @matttuman I think what he means is that you are not showing us your entire code i.e.: the form you're using to post may not be using POST on the method for instance. Which would result on an empty search_term. Also this line is wrong `curl_init($search_term);` should be `curl_init();`

Comment: @Prix - Yeah sorry I should have explained that I echoed out $search_term to make sure it wasn't empty after posting it. I've included my entire code above. Also the name of the script is pagination.php

Comment: @matttuman have not tested your code, but why don't you try to dump the results from your data ? it does not look like the issue is on the form.

Comment: No I don't think the issue is with the form either because I can echo out the posted value with no issue...do you know if posted data is allowed to pass into curlsetopt()? I only ask because again if I just manually assign a value to $search_term ($search_term = 'baseball';) everything works perfectly.

Comment: @matttuman well I have just tested your code exactly as it is posted above and found only 2 errors, which are a missing `}` on the foreach and that your URL have some spaces where shouldnt be. I recommend you to move your `curl_setopt` url into a variable and using the variable into it to make sure on your line breaks u don't have any spaces. Besides that it grabs the data from yt just fine.

Comment: As note on your 2 comment here, you also have the spaces I am talking about, "feeds  /api" and "start-  index" there should be no spaces there i.e.: `'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='.$search_term.'&safeSearch=none&orderby=viewCount&v=2&alt=json&start-index=75&max-results=50'`

Answer (score 0):

I found some syntax errors.
The following code works for me.
NOTE: The change of the filename so you can test this file and update the code in your own file.
Maybe on purpose, but at start it will always do a retrieve with "no terms", since the code is executed.

```
ENTER terms and press Submit button
<form action="ytcurltest1.php" method="post">
<input style="width:50%" type="text" name="search_term">
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?PHP
$search_term = $_POST['search_term'];
$startIndex = 1;
$maxResults = 25;
$ch = curl_init();
$url =  'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='
     . $search_term
     . '&safeSearch=none&orderby=viewCount&v=2&alt=json'
     . '&start-index=' . $startIndex
     . '&max-results=' . $maxResults;
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 

$data = json_decode($output,true);
if ( count($data) == 0 )
  {
    echo 'NO RESULTS FOUND. ENTER other terms';
    RETURN;
  }
$info = $data["feed"];
$video = $info["entry"];
$nVideo = count($video);

echo "<ul style='float:right'>";
foreach ($video as $video)
    {
     echo '<img src="'.$video['media$group']['media$thumbnail'][0]['url']
          .'"><br><br>';
     $title = $video['title']['$t'];
     $video_id = $video['media$group']['yt$videoid']['$t'];
     echo '<a href="search_4.php?video_get_id='.$video_id.'">'.$title.'</a>';
     echo '<br>';
   }
?>
```

Comment: Or you could simple check weather search_term have any entries or isset and if not, skip the later.

Comment: Yes, that is an option. However, it's not wrong to run it initially without any term given, should that be the intention.

Comment: Not entirely, for instance if you have request limitations to the API then doing it for no reason when you can prevent it would obviously be a bad thing. But then again that's not the Q here but yet its a good point to keep in mind.

Comment: I agree with you to prevent the execution of the request, when the file is loaded, if it is not intended. An other option is to split the code in 2 files: the form code apart from the request code. And validate the field with a script done on the client side.